# Proof verification : A compact connected surface, not homeomorphic to a sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, curvature

**Problem:** Let $S$ be a compact connected surface which is not homeomorphic to a sphere. Show
that there are points on S where the Gauss curvature is positive, negative and zero.

If $S$ is a connected, closed (i.e compact and without boundary) surface, I consider the two cases: $S$ is orientable or $S$ is non-orientable.

From the [classification thereom of closed surfaces](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/francisweeks.pdf): If it's orientable, then $\chi(S) = 2-2g$ where $g$ is the number of handles (genus of $S$). Since it's not homeomorphic to a sphere, $\chi(S) \neq 2$ and $g > 0$. If it's non-orientable, then $\chi(S) = 2-h$ where $h$ is the number of crosscaps and since it's not homeomorphic to a sphere, $\chi(S) \neq 2$ and $h > 0$.

So in either case $\chi(S) \leq 0$ and by Gauss-Bonnet $$\int_{S}K = 2\pi \chi(S) \leq 0 $$
the claim follows (elliptic point + intermediate value thereom)

If $S$ is a connected, compact and with boundary, Is this statment even true? In this case, I would have $$\int_{S}K + \int_{\partial S}k_g = 2\pi \chi(S) $$

and I am not entirely sure how this proof would work (if it's true).

Comment: Consider what happens in a cyllinder of height $h$, say. Is is not homeomorphic to a sphere and the curvature vanishes.

Comment: Yeah, That's true. Since cylinder is not a closed surface. So the statement of the problem is actually missing this assumption, correct?

Comment: @Laz It didn't mention "closed" though, only compact and connected.

Comment: But you cite the Classification Theorem, and that is for boundaryless surfaces. So I guess you assumed it. The "closedness" assumption is important though, as @EduardoLonga points out.

Comment: Yeah, I only meant the case when it's without a boundary, but from Eduardo's comment, there is a counterexample if the surface is not closed.

Comment: That's right. I think your proof works fine.